# Add CSV file via XML message

Tags: xml, csv, xsd

I would like to send an CSV file via an XML message which is constructed by an XSD, is there a way to do that? If yes, how.

Comment: I think you need to include more details; as it stands the question is too vague. What does the XSD look like? Example of your CSV input and example of expected XML. And what have you tried so far?

Comment: The XSD is yet to be made, it will be a XML message containing only the CSV file. The CSV file itself can contain 100k+ lines.

Comment: Like to be of any help, but... Why nout just put the entire CSV file content in a CDATA section in your XML "message"?

Comment: The situation is as follows: I have a portal, a client must be able to send a XML message to my portal, this message is check for validity via a specified XSD. Than the file must be stored on the portal and an other customer must be able to reqeust the file via an other XML message. Is the CDATA optioan suitable for this?